# Intellisense doesn't show Page.SaveStateComplete

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I'm editing a VB web page in Visual Studio 2017. I type `AddHandler Page.Save`, IntelliSense doesn't prompt me `SaveStateComplete`.

[image]

However if I spell out the full word, `Page.SaveStateComplete` does exist.

[image]

My Statement completion options don't hide advanced members.

[image]

Can I make Intellisense show `SaveStateComplete`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try disabling "Hide Advanced Members" in the VS options.

Click the Tool Menu and then Options.

Navigate the tree menu

Text Editor --> All Languages --> General

and make sure that "Hide Advanced Members has nothing in it - no tick and no black box.

Comment: Actually I find out VB IntelliSense always hides advanced members.